# What is elementary mathematics?

Tags: soft-question, terminology

In Tao's exposition [What Is Good Mathematics](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2007-44-04/S0273-0979-07-01168-8/S0273-0979-07-01168-8.pdf), he refers to the proof of [Szemerédi's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Szemer%C3%A9di%27s_theorem) as "elementary" but at the same time "remarkably intricate and not easily comprehended". I know that the proof of Szemerédi's Theorem required the development of his [Regularity Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Szemer%C3%A9di_regularity_lemma) which gives a new approach to dealing with large graphs. This leads me to the question of what is really meant when mathematics is described as *elementary*? Why does the proof of Szemerédi's Theorem not fit Tao's definition, and might it fit yours? What are some examples of elementary mathematics, and what are some examples of non-elementary mathematics?

Comment: As you probably imagine, this isn't a precisely defined notion.  The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_mathematics) does pretty well with a general description, I'd say...but obviously the notion is extremely subjective.  As an example, see Selberg's ["Elementary" proof of the Prime Number Theorem](https://www.math.lsu.edu/~mahlburg/teaching/handouts/2014-7230/Selberg-ElemPNT1949.pdf).  I mean, it avoids heavy complex analysis at least.

Comment: I would say something is elementary if it doesn't require lots of developed theory to deal with it. That doesn't imply easy or trivial. For example, school students competitions are elementary, but not necessarily easy.

Comment: @Ennar That was always the definition I was operating on. But in the specific example given by Tao I would definitely have characterised this idea of graph regulaity as quite significant theory, which made me wonder if I have been using this word differently to others.